# Nutch-SOLR Formed Based Authentication

Tags: solr, forms-authentication, web-crawler, nutch

I was going through various links from this forum and other forum. However I was unable to get the exact and good code for this.

Finally I got it and hence wanted to share with you guys.

I could not post the answer so you can see answer given by Jayesh Bhoyar is the correct answer for this question

Comment: This isn't a question. If you didn't find the solution to a problem your were having and then figured it out on your own, you might ask the proper question...then answer your own question and supply the solution. You also might want to read the [SO help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for details on what constitutes good questions and answers.

Comment: Hi Nicholas,
I wanted to share the information with stackoverflow group. None of the links that I visited clearly says that whether this code works or not.
I have tried these code and Now I can surely Say that this code. I just posted this question and answer so that I anybody in future search for this question then they will get the definite answer and they will try these links to resolve their issue

Comment: right. In this case, you want to first ask a question (e.g., "I can't figure out how to do X...", then post it. Then **answer the question you just posted**, along the lines of "*I couldn't find a solution to my problem on SO, but I managed to figure it out on my own. For the record, and to help others in the same boat, here's the solution I found/figured out*...`solution details here`". That keeps the SO question/answer paradigm intact

Comment: Thanks Nicholas will surely take care in Future...